# iOS Charting Library Analysis

Tags: ios, charts

I am working on analyzing different charting solutions for iOS.

Our requirement is:

1. Chart component should be completely customizable.
2. Source code availability is mandatory.
3. Even paid charting solution is ok with us.

I have already gone through the following charting libraries:

1. Telerik (No source code availability)
2. Shinobi Charts.
3. Core plot.
4. iOS charts.
5. Swift charts.

Personally, I feel iOS charts and swift charts are customizable but need to know:

1. Up to what extent it is customizable (Completely or partially)
2. Do they provide complete source code? (So that we can customize the charts according to our requirement)
3. Any other charting libraries available in the market matching our requirement.

Please, advice.

Answer (score 0):

[Syncfusion Essential Chart for iOS](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/ios) can be purchased with the source (requires buying the full Studio product with source) Essential Studio with source

The [charts](http://www.syncfusion.com/products/ios/Chart) are very customizable and we are very interested in customer feedback if further customizations are required. There are ways for you to extend the chart as well.

Note: I work for Syncfusion.